# How to install MetricSpec and learn_runner in Tensorflow 2.x?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, python-3.9

I am trying to train a model in Google Colab and I am getting the following error why I try to import these module -

```
from tensorflow.contrib.learn import MetricSpec
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import learn_runner
```

The error -

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'
```

I know that tensorflow.contrib is not compatible with TF 2.x but I am unable to find any replacement for them.

I am on Python 3.9.16 and Tensorflow 2.12.0

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in **Keras High Level API**.

As you have rightly mentioned, **tf.contrib** was removed quite sometime back.

The API which you have mentioned, **tf.contrib.learn** was replaced by **tf.estimator**. Hence **learn_runner** would then be replaced by **tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate**.

But later even **tf.estimator** was deprecated and the modules are now found in **Keras**.

In **TensorFlow 2.x**, **MetricSpec** has been replaced by the **Metric class** - **tf.keras.metrics.Metric** [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Metric).

For the purpose of running and tuning your experiment, use the **Keras Tuner library** as mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/keras_tuner).

I hope this information works for you.
Thank you !